# H2O “OUTPUT - CLUSTER MEANS” section not report metrics correctly

Tags: h2o

(note: this is related to a question I posted before 
[H2O (open source) for K-mean clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087676/h2o-open-source-for-k-mean-clustering/54119247))

I am using K-Means for our data set of about 100 features (some of them are timestamps)

(1) I checked the “OUTPUT - CLUSTER MEANS” section and the timestamp filed is with the value like “1.4144556086883196e+22”. Our timestamp file is about data in year 2018 and the year 2018 Unix time is like “1541092918000”. Hence, it cannot be that big number “1.4144556086883196e+22”. My understand of the numbers in “OUTPUT - CLUSTER MEANS” section should be close to the raw data (before standarization). Right ?

(2) About standardization, can you use this example https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/test/resources/hex/genmodel/algos/kmeans/model.ini#L21-L27 and tell me how the input data is converted to standardized value? Say, I have a raw vector of value ( a,b,c,d, 1.8 ) , I only keep last element and omit others. How can I know if it’s close to center 2 below in this example. Can you show me how H2O convert the raw data using standardize_means, standardize_mults and standardize_modes. I am sure H2O has a way to compute standardized value from the model output, but I cannot find the place and the formula.
center_2 = [2.0, 0.0, -0.5466317772145349, 0.04096506994984166, 2.1628815416218337]

Thanks.

Comment: for you first question where is this timestamp coming from? just a quick note the timestamp is in milliseconds since unix time (and can correspond to when you ran the model), so you would normally have to divide the h2o-3 timestamp by 1000, however in your case the number still looks to big.

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure where you are seeing a timestamp in Flow or if you mean your dataset contains a timestamp that H2O-3 has converted. Either way it sounds like you may have encountered a bug. The timestamps you see in H2O-3 are milliseconds since the Unix epoch, so you have to divide by 1000 before using a unix time converter (for example you could use https://currentmillis.com/). But again given that the number is so large, I'm leaning towards a bug - any code you can provide to make it reproducible would be great.

1a) When you check `standardize` in flow in addition to “OUTPUT - CLUSTER MEANS” (which is not standardized) you will see "OUTPUT - STANDARDIZED CLUSTER MEANS" so the non-standardize output should reflect the unit of your input.

2) Standardization in H2O-3 is described [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/standardize.html) (which says: "standardizes numeric columns to have zero mean and unit variance. "). The link you provided points to a model for testing that has been saved as MOJO and I'm not sure it makes sense to use as an example. But in general the way standardization works for h2o-3 is as standardization is defined.

Comment: Lauren,
Thanks for your reply
(1) Our data has timestamp column with value like "2018-05-27 00:00:00". This column is detected as "Time" by H2O flow automatically when I load in our CSV file. Then, I run H2O (core) to parse the data. I saw the parse results in "COLUMN SUMMARIES" like "1509494400000.0" which looks right. Then, I run K-menas with those date columns; then in section “OUTPUT - CLUSTER MEANS” section and the timestamp filed is with the value like “1.4144556086883196e+22”. This looks a bug. Perhaps it's related to the one I reported before (see above)

Comment: For (2), I understand the Standardization process, but it's not my question. My question is how H2O reverse process from standardized cluster result back to original values ? I know I can see non standardized result in "OUTPUT - CLUSTER MEANS”. But, I am wondering how H2O convert from standardized result back to non standardized using MOJO file? Hence, I posted the MOJO file as an example...

Comment: okay thanks so much for the clarification! (1) looks like a bug and as you mentioned could be related to your original post, (2) let me get back to you.

Comment: In addition, can you explain how H2O handles handle missing values during training for categorical features ? Say, I have a feature with True, False and missing value(NaN). thanks.

Comment: sure, the way kmeans handles missing values is described in the FAQ at the bottom of the algo page in the user guide (if you are interested in other algos you can go to their section in the user guide). http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/k-means.html

Comment: I did see the FAQ, but it seems not mention categorical features which is my question about. For example, in a column, there are three rows with column values "True (1)", "False (0)" and "NaN (missing value)". What's the missing value (NaN) H2O filled in this example ?

Comment: apologies If I have not understood your question, but the docs list: "Missing values are automatically imputed by the column mean. K-means also handles missing values by assuming that missing feature distance contributions are equal to the average of all other distance term contributions." and categorical handling options are described here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html - please feel free to post another Q on SO with this specific question.